# How to validate block form

Tags: forms, 8, blocks

On Drupal 8.1...

In my custom module hubBlock:

```
namespace Drupal\hub\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


class HubBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {
    [...]
}
```

I have a block form:

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);

  $form['brand'] = array (
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this->t('Brand'),
    '#description' => $this->t('The brand id articles to show?'),
    '#options' => array('0' => t('Select a brand'),"1" => 'brand1',"2" => 'brand2')
  );

  return $form;
}
```

and a block validate function:

```
public function blockValidate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if($form_state->getValue('brand') === '0'){
    $form_state->setErrorByName('brand', $this->t('You need to select a brand'));
  }
  return $form_state;
}
```

When I do place block, I get the form. When I submit without changing the brand I should get an error message and the field should be red. But this only prevent the form to be submitted. There is no error message shown to the user and the field does not get the error class

ref: [blockValidate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetErrorByName/8.1.x)

Is there a bug? Do I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you try with `$form_state->getValue('brand') == 0`? Your code sets an error if `$form_state->getValue('brand')` is a string whose value is `'0'`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I step trough the code with my break points and my if is correct, I do get to the `setErrorByName` line, and the form is not submitted (correct) but there is no error shown and the field doesn't get class error

Comment: I think it is a bug in Drupal core. If you look at `\Drupal\block\BlockForm::validateForm` then it is apparent that they do not gather the validation errors set by your validation method. The validation still fails because the FormState class holds a static variable (`FormState::$anyErrors`) turns to true on any validation error in any FormState object.